# Windows telnet different local echo behavior

Tags: telnet

When I connect to a web server using telnet on port 80, I need to enable local echo to see what I type. However, when I connect to a POP3 server (port 110) the local echo seems to be enabled by default. Why is that? What is the difference?

Comment: This may be more of a superuser question.